# How to iterate through all cells in first 3 columns in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm hving trouble doing so

Right now i can get all rows in my sheet by:

```py
from openpyxl import *

sheet = load_workbook(location)["Sheet1"]
for i in sheet:
    for j in i:
        print(j.value)
```

How can i do so in just the first 3 columns?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using this site: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

anyhow, this is the snippet:

```
from openpyxl import *
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for cell in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col = 3):
    .
    .
    .
```

you can also use ws.iter_rows to access just the values

```
from openpyxl import *
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for cell in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col = 3, values_only = True):
    print(cell) if cell else continue
```